# NPM: combining multiple modules and custom scripts with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, package.json

I have a following script in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "bundle": "browserify index.js > js/bundle.js"
  },
```

index.js contains nothing and only my npm-included modules are bundled into bundle.js.

I am wondering what's the next logical step to go from here?

Prequisities:

- Keep project modular
- Combine npm modules + custom scripts into one bundle.js

Can this be done by using npm as a build tool?

Answer (score 0):

The next logical step is to start writing code in your **index.js** - but that logic is based on the assumption that you want to write your own module.

To kick things off, you would require whatever modules were set in your `dependencies` field in the **package.json**. You would then expose your code via `module.exports`.

Example:

```
var someModule = require('some-module'); /* some external module */

module.exports = MyModule; /* expose your module */

function MyModule () {

  console.log('Hello World!');

  /* do something! */

  someModule(); /* example of using external modules within yours */

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd like to create a custom web dev starter boilerplate where I can download modules from npm and write custom modules, say with revealing module pattern. See the project here: https://github.com/thevangelist/npm-browserify